# Select / name / move newly pasted shape (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Total amateur hour here, learning by doing. I am trying to copy an image in cell U9, paste it and then move it to a certain place in the Excel document (it needs to be placed within a bigger image so pasting it directly to a cell doesn't work).

I am having problems naming and moving the newly pasted image (because the image reference changes every time a new one is pasted). I've found some code that works once (using Shapes.Count) but if the copied image changes (as it needs to), I get the following error when I try to run the code again

Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Method 'Select' of object 'Shape' failed

Any help gratefully received - I'm in the deep end and managing to figure out quite a lot (thanks Stack Overflow) but this has stumped me all day!

```
ActiveSheet.Range("U9").Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("U10").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count).Select
Selection.Name = "Logo 1"
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 130
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 12
```

Comment: What is in cell U9?  You could set a variable to be the new shape/object and use that to make you changes.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow
Maybe this code, without any "Select" usings (which is a very bad practice in VBA), can help you.

This works provided that the image you want to replicate is the last image added in the Sheet, since it's reference always changes.

```
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Copy
        .Cells(10, 21).PasteSpecial

        .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).IncrementLeft 130
        .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).IncrementTop 12

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me on this.

This does work on the first usage, but again, when the shape changes I get run-time error 1004 - 'Application-defined or object-defined error'.

Could I name the pasted shape and then manipulate it from there? How would I do that?

Thanks again!